# Postgres query column with comma-delimited strings for array of strings

Tags: postgresql, array

I have a table that has data that looks like this:

```
id  oe
--  ---------------------------------------------------
 1  04715SNAA90,04715SNAA90ZZ,71501SNAA00,71501SNAA00ZZ
 2  64526915083,64526953474
 3  04715SNAA90,04715SNAA90ZZ,71501SNAA00,71501SNAA00ZZ
 4  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
 5  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
 6  04715SNAA90,04715SNAA90ZZ,71501SNAA00,71501SNAA00ZZ
 7  64526915083,64526953474
 8  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
 9  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
10  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
11  04715SNAA90,04715SNAA90ZZ,71501SNAA00,71501SNAA00ZZ
12  64526915083,64526953474
13  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
14  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
15  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
```

How can I write a query where I can pass an array of values and return rows where that column contains any of the values in the array?

This works because I get another value from a lookup table and I'd rather not do it that way as there is no index on the `hol` column in the `pubnet` table.
[please don't suggest adding one as I cannot modify DB]

```
SELECT * FROM pubnet 
where hol in (select hol from id2hol where id in ('F3DH19860AA', 'F4DHAA'))
```

This would be the result set:

```
id  oe
--  ---------------------------------------------------
 4  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
 5  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
 8  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
 9  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
10  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
13  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
14  F4DH8C607AA,F4DHAA
15  F3DH19860AA,F3DHAA,F4DH19860AA,F4DHAA
```

Comment: Remember to disclose your version of Postgres. And clarify table and column names `hol` or `oe`? A `CREATE TABLE` statement showing names, data types and constraints is always best, and we can easily build a test case from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the comma separated values to an array, then you can use the overlaps operator `&&`

```
select *
from pubnet
where string_to_array(oe, ',') && array['F3DH19860AA', 'F4DHAA']
```

Comment: That is MUCH slower than my other query, 16+ sec to < 3 sec.

Comment: @MB34: shrug. If you violate the rules of normalization then what do you expect? But could create an index on `string_to_array(oe, ',')`

Comment: Yeah, it also doesn't return other records with the same `hol` value(s) that have no `eo` values. Around 40 more records. I'll try to write it a little cleaner, I guess.

Comment: While not good for my uses, I'll accept anyway.